# how did google find my site?

Tags: search-engine, google-search

I created an website. For a week I had an under-construction-page, google did find that paged and indexed it. My question is: How did google find my site, while there were no links to this site and the name has never been used before?

Answer (score 2):

Your domain name went in a domain name server.  Google probably found it there.

Comment: They did find it inside a day, that was fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many websites that automatically gather Whois information of domain names with complete information about them. If you are pretty sure that you have never shown your domain to Google,  i guess these websites did this.

Answer (score 1):

You browser (Chrome) or your browser's plugin might have sent an anonimous report of your browsing statistics to Google - you did open your site in a browser right?

Comment: Yes in chrome and chrome canary

Answer (score 1):

You weren't using a robots.txt file blocking Google.